# Convergence of PDE solution using method of lines

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, boundary-conditions

I'm afraid that this will turn more into a math question rather than a Mathematica one.

I'm trying to solve the equation

$$\frac {\partial n}{\partial t}=D\frac {\partial^2n}{\partial x^2}$$
$$\partial_x n(0,t)=n(0,t)$$

$$\partial_x n(L,t)=1$$
$$n(x,0)=1+x$$

using the code

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{D[u[t, x], {t, 1}] - D[u[t, x], {x, 2}] ==
NeumannValue[u[t, x], x == 0] + NeumannValue[1, x == 10], 
u[0, x] == 1 + x}, 
u, {x, 0, 10}, {t, 0, 10}, Method -> {"MethodOfLines",
"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement"}}]
```

Please note that the initial condition $n(0,x)$ is the function that solves the equation in steady state. So I would be expecting that the solution $n(t,x)$ would stay the same instead of giving the result that you can obtain by running for example:

```
plots = Table[
Plot[sol[i, x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All],
{i, 0, 10}
];

ListAnimate[plots]
```

Please also note that at some point the left boundary condition is not even being respected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a simple sign error in the set up I would think; the left NeumannValues needs a negative sign:

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{D[u[t, x], {t, 1}] - D[u[t, x], {x, 2}] == 
     NeumannValue[-u[t, x], x == 0] + NeumannValue[1, x == 10], 
    u[0, x] == 1 + x}, u, {x, 0, 10}, {t, 0, 10}, 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement"}}];

plots = Table[
   Plot[sol[i, x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All], {i, 0, 10}];
ListAnimate[plots]
Plot[(D[sol[t, x], x] - sol[t, x]) /. x -> 0, {t, 0, 10}, 
 PlotStyle -> Blue]
```

This then gives:

[image]

For details see the 'details' section of the ref page of [NeumannValue](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NeumannValue.html) and also the section [The Relation between NeumannValue and Boundary Derivatives](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementBestPractice.html).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that! So, as far as I understood by those documents, we have to put the minus sign at x=0 because of the way the normal to the boundary is defined?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like a bug. On the other hand, if we correctly formulate the task and use the automatic method, we get the expected result.

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{D[u[t, x], {t, 1}] - D[u[t, x], {x, 2}] == 0, 
   u[0, x] == 1 + x, u[t, 0] == 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(u\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"0", ",", "1"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[t, 0], 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(u\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"0", ",", "1"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[t, 10] == 1}, u, {x, 0, 10}, {t, 0, 10}]



{ContourPlot[sol[t, x], {x, 0, 10}, {t, 0, 10}, 
     PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All],Plot[Table[sol[t, x], {t, 0, 10, 1}], {x, 0, 10}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 20}],Plot[(D[sol[t, x], x] - sol[t, x]) /. x -> 0, {t, 0, 10}, 
 PlotStyle -> Blue]}
```

[image: fig1]